# error with comparing dates to find out max(date) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, transactions, mysql-workbench

I have this query:

> find per account, his last transaction ,for month April, for all
>   accounts using dollars. The results should type: **a)** the account's
>   code
>                            **b)** the last transaction's code (if there are two transactions in one day,  you should type the code fore the
>   latest transaction) 
>                            **c)** the last transaction's date.

My problem is this: how I can compare all the dates for one account?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
         accounts.account_id
         ,transactions.trn_code 
         ,transactions.trn_date
    FROM accounts 
         inner join transactions on accounts.account_id = transactions.account_id
    WHERE 
         accounts.account_currency = 'DOL' 
         and  transactions.trn_date = MAX(transactions.trn_date)
         and transactions.trn_date >= 01/04/2016 and transactions.trn_date <= 31/4/2016
```

This causes an error ( of course) because I cant use MAX like that. But I thought I have to find the max transaction date for this month per account. This thought is right? 
How can I do this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi can you try this

```
 SELECT accounts.account_id, transactions.trn_code , transactions.trn_date
    FROM accounts inner join transactions on accounts.account_id = transactions.account_id
    WHERE accounts.account_currency = 'DOL'   
and transactions.trn_date >= 01/04/2016 and transactions.trn_date <= 31/4/2016 and transactions.trn_date=(Select MAX(transactions.trn_date) from transactions)
group by transactions.trn_code , transactions.trn_date,accounts.account_id
```

Comment: Thanks! it executes now but I dont get the results I want :/
If an account has more transactions than one (between 1/4/2016 - 31/4/2016) the resutls give me all the transactions for this account (each one with his date). But I want only the account's transaction with the latest date.